# Transforming logic circuit to use only NAND gates

Tags: boolean-algebra

How would you go about transforming $BC'(A ⊕ D) + AD'(B' + C)$ to only use NAND gates? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I would begin by asking what is meant by + and (+). My guess would be inclusive and exclusive "or", respectively, but that's only a guess.

Comment: See whether this  [link](http://homepage.smc.edu/kurtz_keith/cs42_supp/NAND_diagrams.htm) helps you.

Comment: @Rohan: Regarding your edit, how are you sure that "(+)" meant $+$ and not $\oplus$?

Comment: Do you know how to make an AND gate out of NAND gates?  How about an OR gate and a NOT gate?  If you know how to do those things, then just replace each AND, OR, and NOT gate with a few NAND gates.

Comment: (+) that means XOR

Comment: Edited the expression to your understanding, I've tried using your link @Rohan still no luck at understanding how it's done :/